# RecyclerView vs LinearLayout for all heterogeneous views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

We have scroll-able screen with 20 views which are all different. At a time, maximum 5 views will be shown. Should I use RecyclerView with 20 different view types to implement it?

Will I get any performance or memory benefit by using RecyclerView instead of LinearLayout in this scenario?

Also, if it makes any difference please consider the case that some of these views may have nested RecyclerViews also with horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I am asking for LinearLayout vs RecyclerView but the question you shared is for LinearLayout vs RelativeLayout.

Comment: Oh sorry I think it was a relativelayout. Ok by the way recyclerview and linearlayout are two different things in terms of showing data. Recycler view is used to show collection of data where as linear layout is simple you just show the data in vertical or horizontal views.